# AndroidStudio not being able to start emulator from avd manager after editing hosts file

Tags: android, android-studio

I had to edit my emulator' hosts file in order to connect to a local development environment. I have followed this steps:

**Run the emulator:**

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -writable-system -avd Nexus_5_API_19
```

**In another terminal/cmd prompt:**

```
adb reboot

adb root

adb -s emulator-5554 remount

adb -s emulator-5554 pull /system/etc/hosts hosts

add the IP to host file

adb -s emulator-5554 push hosts /system/etc/hosts

adb reboot
```

Now whenever I try to start my emulator from AVD Manager it is not responding. I always have to start it with:

```
 ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -writable-system -avd Nexus_5_API_19
```

I mention that I work from High Sierra.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue. You can do following to resolve this

- adb remount
- Cold boot: android studio > avd manager > select the avd> drop down select cold boot
  The emulator will start up.
- close emulator

Now you can start emulator normally.